# mysql select and echo results issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website to learn PHP and have just built a membership app.

Here's my code to get the user cookies that I set when the user logs in, then take the business id they are associated with, called **biz** and look up all the details for the business with the id equal to **biz**, in the table named **company**: (btw, I know I'm using mysql but when I finalize my app, I'll switch to PDO or mysqli)

```
<?
$auth = $_COOKIE["auth"];
if ($auth != "1"){
    header("Location: ./signin.php");
}
//Grab all the cookies

$firstname = $_COOKIE['firstname'];
$id = $_COOKIE['id'];
$fname = ucwords($_COOKIE['firstname']);
$lname = ucwords($_COOKIE['lastname']);
$email = $_COOKIE['email'];
$city = ucwords($_COOKIE['city']);
$biz = $_COOKIE['biz'];

if(!empty($biz)){
    $donthaveabizyet = "false";
}
else{
    include("./config.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE id = '$biz'") or mysql_error();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
           $business_name = $row['name'];
           $business_phone = $row['phone'];
           $business_website = $row['website'];
           $business_phone = $row['phone'];
           $business_cat1 = $row['cat1'];
           $business_cat2 = $row['cat2'];
           $business_cat3 = $row['cat3'];
           $business_subcat1 = $row['subcat1'];
           $business_subcat2 = $row['subcat2'];
           $business_subcat3 = $row['subcat3'];
           $business_email = $row['email'];
           $business_product1 = $row['product1'];
           $business_product2 = $row['product2'];
           $business_product3 = $row['product3'];
           $business_product4 = $row['product4'];
           $business_product5 = $row['product5'];
           $business_product6 = $row['product6'];
           $business_product7 = $row['product7'];
           $business_noaddress = $row['noaddress'];
           $business_address = $row['address'];
           $business_address2 = $row['address2'];
           $business_zipcode = $row['zipcode'];
           $business_city = $row['city'];
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company_secondary WHERE company_id = '$biz'") or mysql_error();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
           $business_description = $row['company_description'];
           $business_since = $row['phone'];
           $business_logo = $row['logo'];
           $business_since = $row['since'];
           $business_smoking = $row['smoking'];
           $business_delivery = $row['delivery'];
           $business_alcohol = $row['alcohol'];
           $business_kids = $row['kids'];
           $business_wheelchair = $row['wheelchair'];
           $business_twitter = $row['twitter'];
           $business_facebook = $row['facebook'];
           $business_youtube = $row['youtube'];
           $business_creditcards = $row['creditcards'];
           $business_outdoor = $row['outdoor'];
           $business_featured = $row['featured'];
     }
}
?>
```

Now I show a link to claim.php if the user's business id is equal to 0, or if the user's business id is set, I show the name of the business.

```
<?php 
if($donthaveabizyet != "false")
{
     echo "<br/><br/>You haven't claimed a business yet. <a href='claim.php'>Click here to claim one now.</a>";
}
else
{
     echo $business_name;
}
?>
```

Unfortunately, $business_name isn't displaying, and the error is `Notice: Undefined variable: business_name`. Why is business_name not set?

Big thanks for all help!!

Comment: inb4, `mysql` is deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: He knows. "btw, I know I'm using mysql but when I finalize my app, I'll switch to PDO or mysqli"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
```

is causing your problem. Change it to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
```

This is because fetch_array creates an array with numeric indexes ($array[1], $array[2], etc.). fetch_assoc makes the indexes the same as the column names ($array['this'], $array['that'], etc.)